# Integrate soft phone in php codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to integrate soft phone in my application made in php codeigniter framework. i want a dial pad with the back end connectivity with sip/softphone to make calls from my application itself. can anyone help me with that..

thanks in advance!!

Comment: you have to use sip client library like sipml5(https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/) and sipjs(http://sipjs.com/).these library are opensource

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need VoIP Server . Install a VoIP server like Asterisk or Freeswitch .

Or you can use a cloud telephony service like Cloudvox or Tropo http://tropo.com (disclosure, I work for Voxeo, the company behind Tropo).

Secondly you need third party library for VoIP related to your server. You Should integrate with your project ,

If you have Third Party Library , then to integrate it read this [Third Party Library integration](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-third-party-libraries-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

Your SIP provider would need to support API-based call requests.   The front-end for that would have to be made by you to suit your app.

For example, have a look at the support documentation for the [Gradwell API](https://support.gradwell.com/hc/en-gb/articles/215552143-How-use-the-call-API-functionality).

Answer (score 0):

You Can use these solution for billing and soft-phone dialer.

https://github.com/openvoips/OV500

Its made in codeigniter 3.

it use Astrick free switch and Kamelio.

it is fully free and opensource

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."  See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)